# postgresql encrypt with symmetric key and rolling it

Tags: postgresql, amazon-kms, pgcrypto

- i want to encrypt data inside a table in postgresql, i may encrypt a few column or all column data in that table.
- if i do query directly from sql client (DBeaver, Adminer) then i can retrieve the column value but it's not readable (because it's encrypted)
- if my application (web apps) query the table data, it will show the readable data. web apps have the correct key to decrypt.

Question :

1. assuming i encrypt using a symmetric key (pgcrypto), how can i regularly rotate the symmetric key ?
2. can i implemented above case at AWS ?